# Java, repeat If statement if the condition was false

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Simplified, I basically have an if statement like this:

```
if(A[random]==1)
    A[random]=0;
else 
    continue;
```

Now I know the 'continue' is for loop statements and this won't work, but I wanted something after the else that if indeed the else(basicaly the condition was false) was activated it repeated the first if(A[random]==1) statement.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for `while(!condition)` ?

Comment: What would the terminating condition of this be?  Is it supposed to terminate after `A[random] == 1`?

Comment: yes it is suposed to end when it finds a bit in the array that is 1 and after it changes it to 0, the if should stop. And with the while statement, it will stop if it finds a bit that is 0 and won't change nothing

Comment: iteration 101 - please attempt to learn basic coding before asking questions online

Comment: I think none of the solution works if array has no bit =1.please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below recursion code and see if this resolve's your query

```
public class Test {


 public void continueIf(){
    if(A[random]==1)
        A[random]=0;
    else {
        continueIf();
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test().continueIf();
 }
}
```

Please note if, if condition is not satisfy then it will lead to stackoverflowerror. That too it depends on the size of JVM memory. check this [link](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/) for more details on stackoverflow error.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but that method would result in a `StackOverflowException`. It needs a `return;`, and even then the logic is buggy.

Comment: I tested it and IT WORKED this is the outcome I wanted, thanks pise

Comment: @MirandaCode as said by @drewkennedy if your if condition do not satisfy then it could lead to `java.lang.StackoverflowError`.

Comment: Well I've ran various iterations of the code, and it has yet to StackOverflowException, soooo all good!

Comment: @MirandaCode i think pise and Drew Kennedy are right.did you check the code with no bit =1 in your array.

Comment: @DrewKennedy where do you want me to add return statement inside if condition. Because I tried both with and without return in if condition both working fine.

Comment: @pise After `A[random]=0;`

Comment: @pise i think all the solutions posted here will fail if  does not satisfy A[random]==1 coz index is randomly generated

Comment: @aa1992 I have already informed mirandacode about this, better if they switch to loop.

Comment: @pise the loops will also fail if the condition is not satisfied.It will be an infinite loop i guess.

Comment: @MirandaCode Your question show you are unfamiliar with simple iteration and boolean conditions, so I suggest you avoid dealing with recursion before you get deeper understanding of the basic building blocks of iterations.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `while` statement instead:

```
while (A[random] != 1) {
    A[random] = 0;
    // generate a new random...
}
```

Comment: My problem with this approach is that I want it to only change one bit in the array from 1 to 0, and if the randomly chosen bit is 0, it won't change anything

Comment: @Mureinik OP 's code should stop when A[random]==1 is satisfied.Your code is doing the reverse.rather it should be A[random]!=1.

Comment: @aa1992 urg, indeed. Got a `==` instead of a `!=`. Fixed.

Comment: @Mureinik A[random]=0 should be outside the while loop.otherwise it changes all the numbers in the array which OP does not want

Answer (score 1):

The if/Else statement won't work by itself with looping through an array. I suggest sticking it in either a For loop or a While loop. The loop will search the array and the if/else statement will check the index for the condition provided. I would also get rid of else too. You don't really need that part just the if.

A for loop in the most basic example would look something like this:

```Java
    for(var i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        {
           if (A[i] == 1)
                 A[i] = 0;
        }
```

SIZE would be the size of your array

Comment: I need it to randomly choose a value from the A array....with that in mind i cannot implement it in a for loop and have A[i], kinda defeats the purpose

Answer (score 1):

```
random = ...;  // get first random number
while (A[random] != 1) {
    random = ...; // get new random number
}
A[random] = 0;  // now is 1, switch it to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.The other answers have described while and recursion so i am 
also adding  a do while loop.

```
 do{
    //generate the  random number
    }while(A[random]!=1)//The loop iterates till the condition A[random]!=1 is satisfied
    A[random]==0;//changing the bit to 0
```

Please note that if  there is no `bit =1` in the array then this solution will fail because you are generating indexes randomly.
So if the array has no `element =1` then it keeps on checking the indexes repeatedly and generates `infinite loop`.

Hope it helps.happy coding!!

Comment: Although this is correct, this answer would benefit by explaining why a `do...while` loop would solve OP's issue instead of only including a code snippet.

Comment: @JNYRanger added explanation.